# clearing multiple labels values

Tags: python, tkinter

I am losing my peanuts here. I am trying to clear two label values but i get an error

```
AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

[image]

basically if i were to click the calculate subtotal button then click the divide total button. I get my intended values. Now if I were to click on the clear values button i get an error. Literally shaking my head as I type this. Anyone care to explain why this is the case?

```
try:
  import Tkinter as tk
 except:
     import tkinter as tk


class GetInterfaceValues():
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.totalValue = tk.StringVar()

    self.root.geometry('500x200')
    self.calculateButton = tk.Button(self.root,
                            text='Calculate Subtotal',
                            command=self.getSubtotals)

    self.divideTotalButton = tk.Button(self.root,
                                     text='Divide total',
                                     command=self.divide)
    self.textInputBox = tk.Text(self.root, relief=tk.RIDGE, height=1, width = 6, borderwidth=2)

    self.firstLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="This is the subtotal:")
    self.secondLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="This is the Divide Total:")

    self.clearTotalButton = tk.Button(self.root, text='clear the values',command = self.clear)

    self.firstLabel.pack(side="bottom")
    self.secondLabel.pack(side="bottom")

    self.textInputBox.pack()
    self.calculateButton.pack()
    self.divideTotalButton.pack()
    self.clearTotalButton.pack()
    self.root.mainloop()

def getTextInput(self):
    result = self.textInputBox.get("1.0", "end")
    return result

def getSubtotals(self):
    userValue = int(self.getTextInput())

    self.firstLabel["text"] = self.firstLabel["text"] + str(userValue * 5)

def divide(self):
    userValue = int(self.getTextInput())
    self.secondLabel["text"] = self.secondLabel["text"] + str(userValue / 10)

def clear(self):
    self.firstLabel["text"] = self.firstLabel.delete("1.0","end")


app = GetInterfaceValues()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
  import Tkinter as tk
except:
  import tkinter as tk


class GetInterfaceValues():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.totalValue = tk.StringVar()

        self.root.geometry('500x200')
        self.calculateButton = tk.Button(self.root,
                                text='Calculate Subtotal',
                                command=self.getSubtotals)

        self.divideTotalButton = tk.Button(self.root,
                                         text='Divide total',
                                         command=self.divide)
        self.textInputBox = tk.Text(self.root, relief=tk.RIDGE, height=1, width = 6, borderwidth=2)

        self.firstLabelDefault = "This is the subtotal:"
        self.secondLabelDefault = "This is the Divide Total:"

        self.firstLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.firstLabelDefault)
        self.secondLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.secondLabelDefault)

        self.clearTotalButton = tk.Button(self.root, text='clear the values',command = self.clear)

        self.firstLabel.pack(side="bottom")
        self.secondLabel.pack(side="bottom")

        self.textInputBox.pack()
        self.calculateButton.pack()
        self.divideTotalButton.pack()
        self.clearTotalButton.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def getTextInput(self):
        result = self.textInputBox.get("1.0", "end")
        return result

    def getSubtotals(self):
        userValue = int(self.getTextInput())

        self.firstLabel["text"] = self.firstLabel["text"] + str(userValue * 5)

    def divide(self):
        userValue = int(self.getTextInput())
        self.secondLabel["text"] = self.secondLabel["text"] + str(userValue / 10)

    def clear(self):
        self.firstLabel["text"] = self.firstLabelDefault
        self.secondLabel["text"] = self.secondLabelDefault
        self.textInputBox.delete("1.0", "end")


app = GetInterfaceValues()
```

You may have confused the methods of `tkinter.Text` and `tkinter.Label`. The method you called was `tkinter.label.delete`, which is not defined (does not exist), however it does exist for the `tkinter.Text`. Therefore, the only way to 'reset' would be to change the `text` attribute of the `tkinter.Label`s back to a 'default' string. It would perhaps be more appropriate to use another widget instead.